# Как воспроизвести анимацию в зависимости от места положения игрока в unity?

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать так чтобы анимация воспроизводилась исходя из того, с какой стороны игрового поля умер персонаж, допустим он исчерпывает свои жизни по левой стороне значит должна воспроизвестись анимация падения влево, если погибает справа, то анимация падения вправо?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял ваш вопрос, но почему бы просто не сравниватьв скрипте, где запускаете анимацию позицию персонажа (`персонаж.GetComponent<Transform>().position`) и сравнить его с какой-то позицией или координатой в мире.

Например, если позиция по Х меньше 10 или больше-равна 10 проигрываются разные анимации:

```
if (персонаж.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x < 10) 
персонаж.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("FallLeft");
else персонаж.GetComponent<Animator().Play("FallRight");
```